# Coq: goal is just a type (when using theorems with unnecessary arguments)

Tags: arguments, coq, coq-tactic

I've discovered a weird quirk in Coq. It happens when you have a theorem with unnecessary arguments, and we use `rewrite` with this theorem. For example, consider the following code snippet.

```
Theorem foo : forall (k : nat) (x : bool), k=0+k.
Proof. reflexivity. Qed.

Theorem bar : forall (k : nat), 0+k=k.
Proof.
  intros k. rewrite foo. reflexivity.
  (* At this point, the goal is just "bool"! *)
Abort.
```

In this example, `foo` has a redundant argument `x`. Then, when I use `rewrite foo` in the proof of `bar`, it generates a goal which just reads "`bool`".

My first question is: why is such a goal generated?

Second, I've discovered that this goal can be completed using the `assumption` tactic. But, this doesn't really show how the goal is resolved. What other tactic could be used to complete such a goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kyo answered your questions well, but I remember being confused about this, so here is some extra context:

In Coq, saying that `X` holds (as in, it was a goal and now it's proved) is the same as saying that there exists a term of type `X` (ie, `X` is inhabited). When `X` happens to be a logical formula (ie, when `X : Prop`), we expect to find it as a goal and to prove it using tactics. When `X` happens to be anything else (eg, `bool`), we expect to find it as a term and use it in definitions. However, there is nothing stopping you from using logical formulas in definitions (often leading to dependent types), proving a logical formula by explicitly providing a proof instead of using tactics (eg `eq_refl : 0 = 0`), or from showing that `bool` is inhabited using tactics.

The distinction is still useful because we often don't care *which* proof was used to show a given theorem, but we often do care which term of type `bool` we have in our hands (although not in your example).

Comment: So if `X` is a goal in Coq, then it's just Coq saying: "give me something of type `X`". Usually `X` is a proposition and we give Coq something of type `X` by filling in a proof. But in general, if `x : X`, then you can just give Coq `x` by writing `exact x`. Did I get that right?

Comment: @Sambo: Yes, that's it!

Answer (score 4):

The goal `bool` is created when you apply the `rewrite foo.` tactic.
At that point you are asking Coq to find expression `ek : nat` and `ex : bool` so that the left hand side of `foo ek ex` occur in the goal. Using unification, Coq infers that `ek := k` is a reasonable choice, but it does not get any information for `ex` since the variable `x` does not appear in the codomain of `foo`. So it creates a fresh goal so that you as as user can fill the missing argument to `foo`.

Now, since that argument is actually unused you have various ways to discharge that goal: you can provide a concrete boolean `exact true.` or `exact false`, leave it to automation `constructor.` or use any boolean you have in your context (I'm actually a bit surprised by the behaviour of assumption is your context is closed as in your example).

You could also supply the argument before Coq creates a goal using `rewrite (foo k true).` for instance.